# No results from PL/SQL query, but there should be.

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql

I know there are several question about this error, also for php.
I've tried most of the answers and nothing seems to work.

This is my query :

```
"select
    id,
    employeenr,
    name,
    section,
    description,
    duration,
    to_date(substr(startdate,0,12)||' '||starttime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') starttime,
    to_date(substr(enddate,0,12)||' '||endtime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') endtime,
    worktime,
    statement,
    remark
    from
    data
    where   1=1
    ".$vw."
    AND startdate between to_date(':df 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date(':dt 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ".$vw1."
    order by nvl(employeenr,0), startdate";
$parameters = array(':df' => $date_from, ':dt' => $date_to);
```

Echo var vw:

```
AND ( employeenr between '100000' and '199999'OR employeenr between '400000' and '499999'OR employeenr between '700000' and '799999'OR (employeenr is not null AND employeenr between '100000' and '199999'OR employeenr between '400000' and '499999'OR employeenr between '700000' and '799999'))
```

$date_from and $date_to:

```
$date_from = $_POST["date_from"]; // jQuery datepicker value
$date_to = $_POST["date_to"]; // jQuery datepicker value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: employeenr between '100000' and '199999'OR - leave a space between OR and '199999'

Comment: The ? stands for a parameter. If you look at the query, at the bottom you'll see $parameters = array($date_from);

Below that, I have posted an echo of that variable.

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil That didn't work sadly

Comment: and what is in `$vw1`?

Comment: what is the '?' inside the query?

Comment: @FlorinGhita That variable is empty in this occasion. The ? is bound by a variable called $date_from, the echo of that var is seen below the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I have been able to fix my problem by stripping out the substr in the SELECT area of the query.

```
$sql_report = "
        select
        id,
        employeenr,
        name,
        section,
        description,
        duration,
        startdate,
        starttime,
        enddate,
        endtime,
        worktime,
        statement,
        remark
        from
        data
        where   1=1
        ".$vw."
        AND startdate BETWEEN to_date('$date_from', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND to_date('$date_to', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
            ".$vw1."
        order by nvl(employeenr,0), startdate";
$parameters = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

How is `$Parameters` used later? It looks as if you want to use it as a *bind varibale* array to pass later to Oracle. If so, then you use this incorrectly, because rather than holding a variable's value the string contains SQL. This is not how bind variables work in Oracle.

You must give Oracle a complete query to parse, only that *values* in the query can be unknown (a date, a number or a string). These you can pass later. You cannot parse half a query and add more SQL in a variable later.

So `AND ?` cannot be parsed, as no value makes sense here. Something like `AND X = ?` could be parsed on the other hand, as Oracle would expect to get the value to compare column X with later when the query gets executed.

Comment: I know, I realised that. I've changed it now, will update it

Answer (score 0):

New question, new answer.

Still you don't use your bind variable for a variable (date, number or string), but try to replace *part* of a string with it. This doesn't work.

`':df 00:00:00'` is a string containing a colon followed by a 'd', an 'f', etc.

Use a bind variable for a complete string, i.e.:

```
AND startdate >= to_date(:date_from, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
AND startdate < to_date(:date_to, 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1
```

or

```
AND TRUNC(startdate) BETWEEN to_date(:date_from, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
                         AND to_date(:date_to, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

or

```
AND startdate between to_date(:date_from || ' 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                  and to_date(:date_to || ' 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Added your code to the query, now getting an literal does not match format string error.

Comment: Your variable must contain a string in the format 'DD-MM-YYYY', e.g. '27-08-2015' without any blanks leading or trailing, with minus for a separator, and with the day and the month really being exactly two digits each and the year having four digits.

Comment: `string(10) "01-06-2015"
string(10) "15-06-2015"`

above values are a var_dump of both post variables

Comment: Then maybe because I renamed the bind variables from df/dt to date_from/date_to? I did that for readability, but of course names must match when binding occurs.

Comment: I've tried all 3 options, all 3 options return literal does not match format string error. Renamned the binded variables from date_from to df and dt

Comment: Strange. I don't have any idea why this is so. As you showed the strings match the format, it must be that Oracle doesn't get them properly, but maybe empty strings instead. I don't know why. I haven't used Oracle with PHP yet, so I don't know how to pass bind variables and what typical errors may occur with that. Sorry.

Comment: No problem man, thakns for trying :) I'd advice you to just use MySQL if you want to have a database behind your PHP. Or NoSQL ofcourse.